# Reading Selected Radio Button on button click

Tags: java, jbutton, actionlistener, jradiobutton

I am trying to get the value of the selected radio button on button click. This is what I managed to do but I am getting null as a result.

//Buttons Declared

```
    JRadioButton choice1 = new JRadioButton("Choice 1");
    JRadioButton choice2 = new JRadioButton("Choice 2");
    JRadioButton choice3 = new JRadioButton("Choice 3");
    JRadioButton choice4 = new JRadioButton("Choice 4");

    choice1.setSelected(true);
```

//Buttons Grouped

```
    ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
    group.add(choice1);
    group.add(choice2);
    group.add(choice3);
    group.add(choice4);

    JPanel radioPanel = new JPanel();
    radioPanel.add(choice1);
    radioPanel.add(choice2);
    radioPanel.add(choice3);
    radioPanel.add(choice4);

    JButton button = new JButton("Check Choice");
    button.addActionListener(new ClickListener(group));
    frame.add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

//Calling Action Listener to read Radio Button Selected

```
    static class ClickListener implements ActionListener{
    ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
    public ClickListener(ButtonGroup group){

        super();
        this.group = group;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        System.out.println(group.getSelection().getActionCommand());
    }
}
```

Comment: whats the question? what is null?

Answer (score 1):

You never set the action commands of your `JRadioButton`s. So, when you ask for it, you're getting null.

### Solution:

Where you first make the buttons:

```
choice1.setActionCommand("1");
choice2.setActionCommand("2");
choice3.setActionCommand("3");
choice4.setActionCommand("4");
```

then in your `actionPerformed` method:

```
String cmd = group.getSelection().getActionCommand();
if(cmd.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
    // Button 1 Action
} else if(cmd.equalsIgnoreCase("2")) {
    // Button 2 Action
} else if(cmd.equalsIgnoreCase("3")) {
    // Button 3 Action
} else if(cmd.equalsIgnoreCase("4")) {
    // Button 4 Action
}
```

This allows you to use the action commands to differentiate between the buttons. It isn't the cleanest way, but it should work.

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

Your ActionListener can query your four JRadioButton instances and check which one is selected with JRadioButton's isSelected() method.

If you want an event to occur when you click a JRadioButton and wish to know what JRadioButton was clicked, you could add an ActionListener to your JRadioButtons and then check if the ActionEvent originated from a specific JRadioButton with something like, e.getSource() == radioButton1.

Comment: I'd recommend using `e.getSource().equals(radioButton1)`, because you are comparing `Object`s and not primitives.

Comment: @AndrewG I don't want to compare what the objects are made up of with e.getSource() == radioButton1, I'd want to compare if the objects are of the same instance. Some custom Swing components could have been used as well which could leave to false positives if you use .equals. It's documented what object will be returned. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EventObject.html#getSource()

Answer (score 0):

You should make all the JRadioButton's static including the ButtonGroup.

Then you need to change the button listener:

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent arg0) {
            System.out.println(group.getSelection().getActionCommand());
        }           
    });
```

And to fix the NullPointerException, use this for all your radiobuttons:

```
choice1.setActionCommand("Choice 1");
```

Comment: It still will print `null` to the console.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
public class Example extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private ButtonGroup group = null;
    private JRadioButton choice1 = new JRadioButton("Choice 1");
    private JRadioButton choice2 = new JRadioButton("Choice 2");
    private JRadioButton choice3 = new JRadioButton("Choice 3");
    private JRadioButton choice4 = new JRadioButton("Choice 4");

    public Example() {

        choice1.addActionListener(this);
        choice2.addActionListener(this);
        choice3.addActionListener(this);
        choice4.addActionListener(this);

        group = new ButtonGroup();
        group.add(choice1);
        group.add(choice2);
        group.add(choice3);
        group.add(choice4);

        JPanel radioPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        radioPanel.add(choice1);
        radioPanel.add(choice2);
        radioPanel.add(choice3);
        radioPanel.add(choice4);

        add(radioPanel);

        setSize(400, 400);
        setVisible(true);

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JRadioButton radio = null;
    if (e.getSource() instanceof JRadioButton) {
        radio = (JRadioButton) (e.getSource());
    }
        if (radio.equals(choice1)) {
            System.out.println(choice1.getText());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes this will work, but it has some holes. Firstly, you should never downcast variables, (like you are with `JRadioButton`) without putting it inside an `if` statement with something like: `if(e.getSource() instanceof JRadioButton)`. Then you know you won't get one of those nasty `ClassCastException`s. Also, +1 on using `.equals()` instead of `==`!